# Internet Explorer Making Images Larger than Normal

Tags: magento

I am having trouble with a custom template I currently have on my website: http://irishgourmet.ie

In the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome and Safari the images in the image placeholder (top right) all load fine and in the correct dimensions. However in the latest version of IE, the first image loads fine then the subsequent images are huge. This trend applies to every category page.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, definitely get your hands on [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) for IE. I use the bookmarklet. It takes a while to load on some versions, but has definitely saved my ass more than once.

Secondly, I'm having quite the opposite problem. I see no issue with the images in the very top right, but if you'r referring to the image carousel on the right, the first carousel image is fine, but the others are being set to

```
width: 178px;
height: 30px;
```

And are loading very small. They look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VouOR.png)

Hope this helps in some way.